# adding and subtracting vectors using structure

Tags: c++, structure, void-pointers

We are supposed to create a "structure" allowing a user to enter two vectors (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and create functions that add and subtract the vectors.  I thought I had the fabric of the code correct, but I'm getting errors at the add and subtract functions and I'm not sure why.  Finals are destroying me.  Please point me in the right direction.

```
/*
v1=(a,b)   v2=(c,d)
v1+v2 = (a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c, b+d)
v1-v2 = (a,b)-(c,d) = (a-c, b-d)

define an array of two mathematical vector structures
each structure consists of two double-precision components, a and b
permit user to enter two vectors, call two functions to return the sum and 
difference
display results calculated

*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector
{
    double X;
     double Y;
} v1, v2;


//prototypes for add and subtract functions
double addVector(Vector vectadd);
double subtVector(Vector vectsub);

int main()
{
    cout << "This program will add and subtract two vectors." << endl;
    cout << "Enter X1: " << endl;
    cin >> v1.X;
    cout << "Enter Y1: " << endl;
    cin >> v1.Y;
    cout << "Enter X2: " << endl;
    cin >> v2.X;
    cout << "Enter Y2: " << endl;
    cin >> v2.Y;

    addVector(v1);
    subtVector(v2);

    return 0;
}

double addVector(Vector vectadd)
{
    cout << "When added together, (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
    cout << "(" << (v1.X + v2.X) << "," << (v1.Y + v2.Y) << ")" << endl;
}

double subtVector(Vector vectsub)
{
    cout << "When subtracted from one another, (x1, y1) - (x2, y2) becomes: " << 
endl;
    cout << "(" << (v1.X - v2.X) << "," << (v1.Y - v2.Y) << ")" << endl;
}
```

edit:
I changed the functions to VOID functions and now the code works as intended.  This is probably not the most elegant way to complete this task tho, right?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector
{
double X;
double Y;
}v1, v2;


//prototypes for add and subtract functions
void addVector (Vector vectadd);
void subtVector (Vector vectsub);

int main()
{


cout << "This program will add and subtract two vectors." << endl;
cout << "Enter X1: ";
cin >> v1.X;
cout << "\nEnter Y1: ";
cin >> v1.Y;
cout << "\nEnter X2: ";
cin >> v2.X;
cout << "\nEnter Y2: ";
cin >> v2.Y;
cout << endl;

addVector (v1);
subtVector (v2);


return 0;
}

void addVector (Vector vectadd)
{
cout << "When added together, (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
cout << "(" << (v1.X + v2.X) << "," << (v1.Y + v2.Y) << ")" << endl;
}

void subtVector (Vector vectsub)
{
cout << "When subtracted from one another, (x1, y1) - (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
cout << "(" << (v1.X - v2.X) << "," << (v1.Y - v2.Y) << ")" << endl;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: _but I'm getting errors_ Which are...? I bet they tell _exactly_ what is wrong.

Comment: why are your functions missing the return statement....??

Comment: If the variables are global, why are you passing one of them to `addVector()` and `subVector()`?

Comment: @Jim Tribble: Your program can be written in a better way, but anyway it works and gives correct results. so what errors do you get?

Comment: The error is "control reaches end of non-void function".   There is one error at the end of each void function.  I think it has something to do with returning a value?

Comment: The instructions of the program were to create a structure and then to create an add function and a subtract function.  I'm sure I could add and subtract them without the functions, but thats not what the instructions say.

Comment: how should I write the return statement?  I tried different return statements and couldn't get them to work :(

Comment: May be your compiler requires returning a value. add `return` to the functions or make them`void`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Each of your function calls passes a single argument to a function that looks like it is intended to operate on the member variables from 2 structures...?  How do your functions know about the other values?  Your addVector function knows about v1 and your subtVector function knows about v2 but neither function knows about both...?  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @drt ahh, i see what you're referring to but I don't understand how I would fix it properly...

Comment: @Jim Tribble I was trying to lead you to a solution rather than dump one in your lap...hoped you would get your book out and dig into how functions and struct/class instances work

Answer (score 0):

your code is not compiling, the reason is in the message:

> 'subtVector': must return a value

hint, the function should return a vector too,
the addVector function could look like:

```
Vector addVector(Vector& vA, Vector& vB)
{
    Vector r;
    r.X = vA.X + vB.X;
    r.Y = vA.Y + vB.Y;

    cout << "When added together, (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
    cout << "(" << r.X << "," << r.Y << ")" << endl;
    return r; 
}
```

same applies to  **subtVector**

Comment: This is a great way to clean up what I posted.  I missed a few things and you pointed them out perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Functions either `void` or has other datatypes.

Note that:

```
void f()
{
    // this function does something, but it does NOT have to return anything because 
    //it is a void function 
}
```

but

```
int fun()
{
  // does something
  return expression;
}
```

This function has to return a value as it is not a `void` function. and in this case it has to return an `int` value.

function of `void` type can be called directly

```
//code
f();
// code
```

but `non-void` function can be assigned to other variables like:

```
// code
v = fun();
```

or can be part of an expression like

```
//code
cout << 5 + fun();
```

So...

Make your functions void like this

```
void addVector(Vector vectadd);
void subtVector(Vector vectsub);


void addVector(Vector vectadd)
{
   // your code
}

void subtVector(Vector vectsub)
{
   // your code
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a vector from the functions instead of `double`.

```
Vector addVector (Vector , Vector);
Vector subtVector (Vector , Vector);

int main()
{
    // your code
    Vector V;

    cout << "When added together, (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
     V = addVector (v1, v2);
    cout << "(" << V.X << "," << V.Y << ")" << endl;

     V = subtVector (v1, v2);
    cout << "When added together, (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) becomes: " << endl;
    cout << "(" << V.X << "," << V.Y << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}

Vector addVector (Vector v1, Vector V2)
{
    Vector Result;
    Result.X = v1.X + v2.X;
    Result.Y = v1.Y + v2.Y; 
    return  Result;
}


Vector subtVector (Vector v1, Vector V2)
{
    Vector Result;
    Result.X = v1.X - v2.X;
    Result.Y = v1.Y - v2.Y;   
    return  Result;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Code is so funny how its both creative/artistic AND mathematical in that there are many ways to do it right, AND many ways to do it wrong.  Thanks so much for showing me this.

Comment: @Jim Tribble: if you like the answer would you please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the correct mark next to the answer as described in [*this page*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),  Also it will be good for you if you read [*this page*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for better asking. They were helpful to me. – Kamal Zidan May